# Android jpg animation

Tags: android

I would like to download 10 JPG pictures from a site.

The pictures where taken at intervals >> that is no problem

1. How do I save pictures in an array of pictures.
2. How would I show them as a moving picture (movie like).
3. What component to use on Android (imageView, animator)?
4. How would I animate the component?

Any specific examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you a response is helpful, pleas up vote it. If the response successfully answers you question please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an example of this, here I am downloading three images form site and then store in it path "/mnt/sdcard/..". If you want to show this in animation then I think that you can use flipper and then add this image dynamically and using an async task you can flip image next.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button btn;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
        final String url1 = "http://farm1.static.flickr.com/114/298125983_0e4bf66782_b.jpg";
        final String url2 = "http://farm1.static.flickr.com/114/298125983_0e4bf66782_b.jpg";
        final String url3 = "http://farm1.static.flickr.com/114/298125983_0e4bf66782_b.jpg";
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new AsyncDownload().execute(url1,url2,url3);
            }
        });
    }

    //------------------------------Class AsyncDownload----------------------------------

    public class AsyncDownload extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);    
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this,"Downloading complate successfully",2).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog=new ProgressDialog(TestActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Downloading file..");
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            dialog.setMax(100);
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            dialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
            int count;
            int lenghtOfFile=0;
            long total = 0;
            try {
                for(int i=0;i<aurl.length;i++)
                {
                    URL url = new URL(aurl[i]);
                    URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                    conexion.connect();
                    lenghtOfFile =lenghtOfFile+conexion.getContentLength();
                }
                for(int i=0;i<aurl.length;i++)
                {
                    URL url = new URL(aurl[i]);
                    URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                    conexion.connect();
                    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/img"+i+".jpg");

                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];               

                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                        total += count;
                        publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                    }

                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                    input.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();

            }
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: 1. i will use your idea to store 10 jpg files 2.but now for the real problem i need to animate the 10 jpg pictures at interval of let say 300 msec. to have a movie like effect. how to do that.what component to use?

Comment: Use AnimationDrawable as in my answer. Loop through your images and call addFrame(yourDrawable, 300), where 'yourDrawable' is your downloaded drawable, and '300' is the individual frame duration.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to use [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) in an `ImageView`.

Add frames using the `addFrame(Drawable frame, int duration)` method, and start the animation using `start()`.

You can use many different methods to download and store the image (perhaps to external storage, or a db).

Comment: @Shlomo - If one of our answers helped you, please accept it by clicking on the check mark.