# Android java load images from url

Tags: java, android

I have a question

```
private final String images[] = {"http://developer.android.com/images/dialog_custom.png", "http://developer.android.com/images/dialog_progress_bar.png"};
```

how can i change this

to load all of the links from a file from my website?

like a .txt on my site just has like

```
http://link.com/1.png
http://link.com/2.png
http://link.com/3.png
http://link.com/4.png
http://link.com/5.png
http://link.com/6.png
http://link.com/7.png
http://link.com/8.png
http://link.com/9.png
http://link.com/10.png
```

so it will just load all those then later on i can add more links without having to update the app

Comment: you should visit this link may it help you!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162568/android-jpg-animation/8162697#8162697

Answer (score 2):

Use a `BufferedReader` to `readLine()` to a `String` and then fetch the image...

Answer (score 0):

Just put the space or "," or "/n" in file then get all data in a string one by one

```
String reader = "";
String separated ;

BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("YourFileName.txt"));
while ((reader = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
    separated = reader.split(" "); or reader.split(","); or reader.split("/n");
    //Here at each itration separated will have your single link
}
buffer.close;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try out the following links:

1. [How to load an ImageView by URL in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)
2. http://russenreaktor.wordpress.com/2009/08/11/android-imageloader-load-images-sequencially-in-the-background/

There are plenty of links that provide solutions--enjoy.

Comment: He wasn't really asking how to load the image; he was asking how to be able to dynamically get ALL of the images without hardcoding them in the app.